# How to remove formatting in the json message generated by fasterxml jackson

Tags: json, jackson

We are using the following API to convert our object & it's value to JSON format string. Now one of our requirement says, the generated string should not be formatted using TAB or extra spaces. I do not want to remove the whitespaces that is part of the actually content but should remove only the whitespaces & tabs in the overall json message formatting. Is there any option/api using which this can this be achieved ?

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonMessage = mapper.writeValueAsString(myObject);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to disable Indentation:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
```

You can find more options for serialisation here: [Jackson Serialisation Features](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Serialization-features)